# Why the ContinueWith() starts BEFORE the previous task completes

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, multitasking

I'm trying to create a task that will wait for some time and then continue with some post-task work. The code shows as below. If I use Thread.Sleep() for the waiting time, it works as expected. However, if I change Thread.Sleep() into await Task.Delay(), the continuation occurs BEFORE task1 finishes. How did it happen?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Task t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3))
                              .ContinueWith((prevTask)=> { Console.WriteLine("post task work!!!"); });

        Console.WriteLine("caller after starting tasks");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task DoSomeVeryImportantWork(int id, int sleeptimeInSeconds)
    {
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        Console.WriteLine($"t{id} is beginning");

        stopWatch.Start();
        //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sleeptimeInSeconds));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sleeptimeInSeconds));
        stopWatch.Stop();

        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
           ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
           ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine($"t{id} sleeping time -  " + elapsedTime);
        Console.WriteLine($"t{id} has completed ");
    }

}
```

Expected Output: (this is also the output if I use thread.sleep() instead of task.delay())

```
caller after starting tasks
t1 is beginning
t1 sleeping time -  00:00:03.00
t1 has completed
post task work!!!
```

Actual Output:

```
caller after starting tasks
t1 is beginning
post task work!!!
t1 sleeping time -  00:00:03.01
t1 has completed
```

Comment: Perhaps because your Task is defined as async? It will appear to exit while it is awaiting the first result.

Comment: @Steve Todd I don't think that will be a problem, though. Because although the Task is async, it is `await DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3)` rather than `DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3)`, which means it should only return after DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3) finishes. Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: But your Task.Delay() is awaited. It will pass control back to the caller while it is awaiting that.

Comment: Bottom line: Don't use `StartNew` or `ContinueWith`. Use `async` and `await` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@Steve rights. `await` returns a new `Task` - it equals to `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3))`... You have two options:

1) Using `Task.Run()`, which handles async tasks correctly:

```
Task t1 = Task.Run(() => DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3));
// Or
Task t1 = Task.Run(async () => await DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3));
```

2) Do not call `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. Simply call the async method, and the task will be started automatically:

```
Task t1 = DoSomeVeryImportantWork(1, 3);
```